# Eurorack PSU design and noise

Tags: power-supply, noise, wall-wart

I'm trying to design a cheap way to power my DIY Eurorack modules. I'm trying to use two 15V wall warts to that effect but I'm getting a lot of noise. I've seen a few questions related to noise induced by PSU, but I think mine is different.
So here are a few pics of my design, what am I doing wrong?
[image]

[image]

Here are some scope measurements:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the noise have a distinct frequency? What do the Eurorack modules do?

Comment: Is it possible that what you describe as noise, others would describe as signal? Why not?

Comment: @AndrewMorton By noise I mean a signal added to the signal I send

Comment: @AndrewMorton The Eurorack modules generate or process audio signals

Comment: The power supplies that provide power to your regulator are unknown. Please tell what they are, how they are connected to your regulators, and how they connect to some upstream power source like mains voltage.

Comment: Is the noise present on the power supply rails, or might it be induced onto the amplifier inputs somehow? *Where* in the circuit are you detecting noise?

Comment: @Justme Like I said they are two 15V AC/DC wall warts.

Comment: @AndrewMorton At the output of the module when no input is provided

Comment: btw my mains are 230V 50Hz

Comment: Also, I am totally open on another design using two wall warts as a power source!

Comment: @brunobhr (1) What is the noise when there is an input? (2) You've only shown some power supply circuitry. (3) Do you have any evidence that the mystery audio generation/processing modules work as you expect with any other power supply? Maybe they've gone a bit flaky with age?

Comment: @AndrewMorton The modules work fine when powered with my Rigol DC lab supply (no 'noise'). The modules are fresh built with new components

Comment: @brunobhr What noise do you observe on the inputs and the outputs of the power supplies? Maybe some extra capacitors of values like 10 nF would help: it might be easy to give it a quick check.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I don't understand your question. The input is mains. Also, where should these 10nF caps be located?

Comment: @brunobhr Saying that they are two 15V AC/DC wall warts means literally nothing which is why I asked for details. Whicn kind, make, model, switch mode or linear, regulated or unregulated, earth referenced or floating, knowing these kind of details are needed to solve the problem.

Comment: @Justme https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wall_wart Just regular cheap AC/DC wall warts like there are millions..what's unclear? thank you

Comment: @brunobhr I know what warts are. I need know which exact wall warts you happen to have to help you. You might have the noisy switch mode types, or the noiseless linear types, or the unregulated typed. But I can't know which kind of wall warts you have unless you give details which wall warts you have.

Comment: Switch mode, in any case the most basic wall wart you find everywhere. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_adapter#/media/File:Wall-Wart-AC-Adapter.jpg

Comment: @Justme As I said, I just took a wild guess assuming that'd work. If that kind of PSU is impossible to make out of basic switch wall warts, I will try to find another solution

Comment: @brunobhr No, it is possible, but you need to select which kind of electronics they have in them. For your case of audio, do not use switch mode power supplies. Use unregulated or regulated linear power supplies. When you buy wall warts, you need to know what you are buying to know if it is suitable for what you need it. If you don't show or identify what you have now, we cannot say if these specific power supplies are suitable for your use case. Generally, devices have a label with make and model printed on them along with other info like "switch mode power supply". What reads on the labels?

Comment: @Justme My point was to use cheap switch wall warts opposed to costly linear supplies exactly, hence my question.

Comment: I built a Eurorack module with a linear (transformer, bridge rectifier) PSU. Simple and not particularly costly. Generic wall warts are not going to give you a low noise solution.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be using switch mode wall warts as power supplies.

These output a lot of electrical noise, both differential mode and common mode.

One solution is to buy anothet set of wall warts that are not switch mode power supplies. Another solution is to make your PCB to be more complex and expensive to filter or smooth away the noise.

For this purpose, the regulator input capacitors are too small. You need few tens if not a few hundred microfarads, preferably after a resistor or inductor to have an RC or LC filter to remove noise.

As electrolytic caps are quite poor at high frequencies, having one larger electrolytic and one 100nF ceramic for filtering high frequencies would be much better. Unless you buy polymer electrolytics.

The PCB wiring is also quite narrow, wider tracks would pass more current with less voltage drop. It could be a lot better. It's two-sided, with both sides mostly etched empty from copper that could have been used to make a proper ground plane and wide tracks to easily carry a lot of current.

Comment: Thanks justme! I will try changing caps values and try it out. I'll let you know!

Comment: I tried with different combination of caps values, but couldn't get to a satisfying result. So as suggested by @Ian Bland, I might just try the linear and bridge rectifier way. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Wall-warts are classified as SMPS(switch-mode power supply). These are different to linear PSUs in that they waste very little power as heat(more efficient) however this introduces a LOT of noise into the output. Your 78/79xx linear regulators will attenuate some of this noise, however higher frequency noise will go straight through. As a general example, the [STMicroelectronics 7805](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2307057.pdf) has the following ripple rejection plot: [image]

This may look pretty good, however is only good for low frequency noise(e.g. 50/60 Hz powerline) up to about 100khz(10^5 Hz), at which the attenuation starts dropping. Unfortunately, SMPS supplies typically have a lot of noise in the MHZ region, and are not filtered out by the 78xx regulators very well.

A solution to this is to add a LC power filter between your regulators and the wall-wart to filter out this HF noise, with a ferrite bead instead of an inductor as the L element in the filter(beads have the property of having a higher resistance at increasing frequencies, starting at around the 1 MHZ range up to 100MHZ). Rigorous testing of this filter is required with some sort of simulation program(LTspice, etc) for optimal frequency response, it depends on how clean you want your supply.

Comment: If you look at the scope, the ripple voltage has a frequency of around 500 kHz as measured by the scope.and based on the pulses on the waveform, around 1 MHz. Please explain how a ferrite bead will remove such a ripple, as they are generally rated with impedance at 100 MHz, which is 100x higher. Which kind of ferrite bead you mean, maybe you mean a different component called a ferrite bead than what I think when someone says ferrite bead.